# Python Opencv high resolution bug

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using opencv as part of a beam profiler software. For this I have a high resolution camera (5496x3672, Daheng Imaging MER-2000-19U3M). I'm using now a basic program to show the captured frames. The program works fine for a normal webcam, however when I connect my high resolution camera (through USB 3.0) it becomes buggy. Most of the frame is black and at the top there are three small instances of the recording ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VNq.jpg)). On the other hand, the camera software displays the image properly, so I assume there must be a problem in how opencv access the camera. Here is the code used to diplay the image:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,5496)
cap.set(4,3672)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame2=cv2.resize(frame,(1280,720))
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame2)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try changing `cv2.waitKey(1)` to something like `cv2.waitKey(1000)`. Another option would be to write the frame to a video using `cv2.VideoWriter()`.

Comment: I tried this to no avail, but thanks for your response.